# Convert Nested Dictionaries to Deedle Frame

Tags: f#, deedle

A nested dictionary contains the following data: {names, {dates, prices}}

The structure is so:

```
type Dict<'T, 'U> = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<'T, 'U>
let masterDict = Dict<string, Dict<Datetime, float>> ()
```

The raw data looks like:

```
> masterDict.Keys |> printfn "%A"
seq ["Corn Future"; "Wheat Future"] 

> masterDict.["Corn Future"] |> printfn "%A"
seq   [[2009-09-01, 316.69]; [2009-09-02, 316.09]; [2009-09-03, 316.33]; ...] 

> masterDict.["Wheat Future"] |> printfn "%A"
seq   [[2009-09-01, 214.4]; [2009-09-02, 223.86]; [2009-09-03,
    234.11];    [2009-09-04, 224.62]; ...]
```

I'm trying to full outer join the data above into a Deedle frame like so:

```
            Corn Future   Wheat Future
2009-09-01  316.69       214.4
2009-09-02  316.09       223.86
2009-09-03  316.33       234.11
2009-09-04  NaN          224.62           // in case a point is not available
```

The mechanics of Deedle are still alien to me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I wrote the answer, but to me it seems a bit ugly. You need to use the alias (Dict) ? You have the opportunity to show how you fill masterDict?

Comment: I just think it can be done easier.

Comment: as Foggy says, you can just use the `dict` function to create the dictionary. No need for a type alias.

Comment: I'll switch to using dict, but i didn't know any better. The above dictionary is the result of querying the bloomberg api. I translated the C# example on http://www.bloomberglabs.com/api/libraries/ to F#.

Answer (score 3):

There are some extension methods in Deedle library (mainly to make it friendly to C# too), which work with `KeyValuePair` as opposed to tuples (which is the default for F#).

So you should be able to simplify the answer that Foggy Finder posted a little (assuming you have `open Deedle` at the top):

```
let frame = 
    masterDict
    |> Seq.map(fun kv -> kv.Key, kv.Value.ToSeries())
    |> Frame.ofColumns

frame.Format() |> printfn "%s"
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are going to join, but you can just transform:

```
let frame = 
    masterDict
    |> Seq.map(fun kv -> kv.Key, kv.Value 
                                 |> Seq.map(fun nkv -> nkv.Key, nkv.Value)
                                 |> Series.ofObservations)
    |> Frame.ofColumns

frame.Format() |> printfn "%s"
```

Then you got:

```
                      Corn Future Wheat Future
01.09.2009 0:00:00 -> 316,69      214,4
02.09.2009 0:00:00 -> 316,09      223,86
03.09.2009 0:00:00 -> 316,33      234,11
04.09.2009 0:00:00 -> <missing>   224,62
```